# How do i know which client is sending the message in a multi threaded server

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server, client

I am creating a client server architecture (JAVA) and every time a clients connects to the server , a new thread is spawned for the client. My issue is that there will be multiple clients sending messages to my server and I have no idea which client is sending the message. The client and server is hosted on the same computer

I have a function : `ReadFromClient` which reads the input from the client

How do I know which client is sending the message ??

**Code for the thread which will be spawned**

```
package javaassignment3;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class NetConnectClientHandler implements Runnable
{

    public  Socket clientSocket;
    public  Thread t;
    public  int serverNumber;

    public  PrintWriter out;
    public  BufferedReader in;

    public String msg;

    boolean cont;
    boolean cont2;

    public NetConnectClientHandler(Socket s,int serverNumber)
    {
        this.cont = false;
        this.clientSocket = s;
        this.serverNumber = serverNumber;
        t = new Thread(this);


        //setup the server
        try
        {
             out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
             in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        }
         catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Read or write to socket failed.");
            System.exit(2);    
        }

        t.start();
    }

    public  void WriteToOneClient(String inputLine,int index)
    {
        NetConnectThreadedServer.clientList.get(index).out.println(inputLine);
        //out.println(inputLine);
    }

    public void WriteToAllClient(String inputLine)
    {
        int i =0;
        for (NetConnectClientHandler client : NetConnectThreadedServer.clientList)
               {
                   client.WriteToOneClient(inputLine,i);
                   i++;
               }
    }

    public String ReadFromClient()
    {
         String inputLine;
        try
        {
               inputLine=in.readLine();
               return inputLine;
        }
           catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Read or write to socket failed.");
            System.exit(2);    
        }


        return "willneverreachhere";

    }

    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Threaded Server number " + serverNumber + " started");

       for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
       {
           String r = ReadFromClient();
             if (r.equals("123_3"))
           {
               cont2 = true;
               System.out.println("HeHe");
           }


       }



        System.out.println("Threaded Server "+serverNumber+" socket closed");


    }
}
```

**Code for the client**

```
package javaassignment4;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class NetConnectClient 
{
     public static JFrame jframe;

     public static String hostName;
     public static int port;
     public static InetAddress ina;
     public static Socket s;
     public static DataOutputStream writeToSocket;
     public static DataInputStream readFromSocket;

      public static BufferedReader d;
      public static byte[] inputBuffer;



     public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        jframe = new JFrame();
        jframe.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1250,750));
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        new NetConnectClient().run();

        System.out.println();
    }



    public void run()
    {

        Utility.SetUpConnection();
    }

    public static void SetUpConnection()
    {
        //make sure the server is started before running the client
        NetConnectClient.hostName = "localhost";
        NetConnectClient.port = 4445;

        InetAddress ina = null;
        try
        {
            //internet address , hostname
            ina = InetAddress.getByName(NetConnectClient.hostName);
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException u)
        {
            System.out.print("Cannot find host name");
            System.exit(0);
        }

         NetConnectClient.s = null;
        try
        {
            //try to connect to host
            NetConnectClient.s = new Socket(ina,NetConnectClient.port);    

        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.print("Cannot connect to host");
            System.exit(1);
        }

         NetConnectClient.writeToSocket = null;
         NetConnectClient.readFromSocket = null;

        try
        {
            //create the read,write socket
            NetConnectClient.writeToSocket = new DataOutputStream(NetConnectClient.s.getOutputStream());


            NetConnectClient.readFromSocket = new DataInputStream(NetConnectClient.s.getInputStream());
        }
        catch(IOException io)
        {
            System.out.print("Cannot setup read write");
            System.exit(2);            
        }

        //variable to store user input
        NetConnectClient.d = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        //variable to read whatever server has written
        NetConnectClient.inputBuffer = new byte[2048];
    }



}
```

Comment: well, you could try to print each object's "this", I guess

Comment: @Leo Client is passing a string to the server , how do you print this object ??

Comment: I am not sure if this's what you want, but you can buffer your streams and consume it from two different endpoints (one to the other end, as expected, and another for your logging) using something like Pipe Streams (this is not exactly an example but I think you can get the idea - http://www.cs.rtu.lv/PharePub/Java/Tutorial/essential/io/pipedstreams.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try Socket.getInetAddress() on server side which returns the remote IP address to which this socket is connected,

Comment: I dont think it works, both my client and server is on the local host, i get the results : 127.0.0.1 for all clients

Comment: Then the only way out is client should send its ID after connect